# I'm confused about how encapsulation should work

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, software-design, solid-principles

Hi. Today I wanted to play with concepts of good OOP design and I tried to write an application for a movie store where customers can buy movies from movie store. I have three classes in it. A class that represents a movie store and a class for customers and another for movies.

Now my question is: Is it good to let customers create instances of movies for themselves without buying it from movie store? Should I trust programmers that wrote the customer class? Is this problem related to encapsulation?

Comment: Please show us that you did, so we can help you with the design. 
Besides, please becareful when tagging, this is no anything related to java yet.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Customers and movies are state, they're what your classes should know about (encapsulation) and talk about (message passing) not what your classes should model. Design your classes around solution system responsibilities, not problem domain entities.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation means declaring Data members as private and accessing them via public methods like setters and getters. For your example, in your scenario, you want to have a private variable of type Movie. You can access the Movie via a public get method in where you could have some sort of authorization before accessing the Movie object. The same goes for setter method. This is called Encapsulation.For example, see the basic implementation:

```
class MovieStore{

    private Movie currentPlaying;

    public Movie getCurrentPlayingMovie(){    //Get method
        if(authorizationMethod()){
            return currentPlaying;
        }
        //Authorization failed

        notifyAuthorizationFailed();
        return null;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayingMovie(Movie m){    //Set method
        //Same like above
    }

}
```

If you had declared the Movie object as public, anyone can directly access the movie object and you can't have any authorization. While developing software, it might seem like a data member does not need to have any protection. But it may be required in future, so it is better to always implement Encapsulation(by declaring them as private and adding setters and getters to that member) so you can edit the methods whenever you need.